# Weird DateTime parsing behaviour

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I am noticing this weird behavior when parsing 2 string to DateTime.
The first string (causes exception) "20/10/2013 3:08:30 AM"
The second string (converts correctly with no exceptions) "9/10/2013 3:09:37 AM"

The code used to convert is :

```
string date_1 = "20/10/2013 3:08:30 AM";
string date_2 = "9/10/2013 3:09:37 AM"; 
try
{
DateTime d1 = DateTime.parse(date_1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);   //throws exception (String was not recognized as a valid DateTime)
} catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
DateTime d2 =  DateTime.parse(date_2, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
```

Can anybody please explain why 2 strings representing full date with the same format do this?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: There is no 20th month... Use correct culture for parsing or correct format for "ParseExact" to fix.

Comment: Sounds like an mm/dd/yyyy vs. dd/mm/yyyy error... did you check the month and day fields in d2 after parsing? Are they what you expect i.e. day=9 month=Oct?

Comment: What is the default date format for the CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ? 
Is it MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt    or   dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt ?

Comment: Both dates were supposed to be "dd/MM/yyyy ...."

Comment: @Rafael - [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/az4se3k1.aspx): "For the invariant culture, this pattern is "MM/dd/yyyy""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will throw because US date notation expects month as first field:

```
string d = "20/10/2013 3:08:00 AM";
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse(d, new CultureInfo("en-US")));
```

Same for InvariantCulture.

This will work:

```
DateTime.Parse(d, new CultureInfo("nl-NL"))
```

Comment: Is the InvariantCulture same as "en-US" ? and what is the "nl-NL"?

Comment: nl-NL is forcing Dutch regional setting for parsing this particular string to DateTime. 'The custom format string for the invariant culture is "MM/dd/yyyy"', as seen here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: nl-NL was just an example to show when it works as in netherlands the day is the first field in a month

Comment: Thank you for the information, it turned out that i was saving the date in the xml as UTC with InvariantCulture format "MM/dd/yyyy" which caused the exception when parsing. 

Thank you again for the answer.

Comment: +1. @Rafael - for XML you should use "O" as format (ISO8601 `2013-10-10T03:08:00`)... So much easier to deal with...

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the culture when parsing a date. If your computers location settings are correct for your region and so is the date then you can simply parse with the current culture.

E.g.

```
string date = "20/10/2013 3:08:00 AM";    
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse(date, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture));
```

Or simply:

```
string date = "20/10/2013 3:08:00 AM";    
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse(date));
```

This will work for me here in Australia, however if your regional settings are for the US for example then you would need to specify the culture you expect the date to be formatted in. E.g.

```
string date = "20/10/2013 3:08:00 AM";    
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse(date, new CurrentUICulture("en-AU")); //en-GB, etc
```

That being said it is quicker (and perhaps safer) to use `DateTime.TryParse` if you expect the date format to be incorrect.

Comment: I know that, but i want a date that works on all cultures, that is why i used the CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.

Comment: You have to know the format of the date before it can parse it. For example 1/10/12 means different things depending on which culture it was entered in. Your best bet is to store the culture with the date or store it in a universal format like yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: Yes thank you, i am already using the DateTime.UTCNow to get the date.